# Table scan on Redshift table even with sort keys

Tags: amazon-redshift

We have a large table in Redshift where we are storing our AWS billing files and querying them. We are using interleaved sort keys as not all queries have all the filters.

Running this query

```
select "column", type, encoding, distkey, sortkey, "notnull" 
from pg_table_def
where tablename = 'accountbillingflat' 
and sortkey <> 0
order by sortkey;
```

Gives this result

[image]

Now if we execute the following query

```
SELECT
    payeraccountid,
    linkedaccountid,
    billingmonth,
    updatedon    
FROM
    accountbillingflat    
WHERE
    linkedaccountid IN (
        '123'    
    )    
    AND billingmonth IN (
        201603    
    )    
GROUP BY
    payeraccountid,
    linkedaccountid,
    billingmonth,
    updatedon    
ORDER BY
    billingmonth desc,
    updatedon desc
```

The plan for query execution is

```
XN Merge  (cost=1000002059236.65..1000002059237.77 rows=445 width=44)
  ->  XN Network  (cost=1000002059236.65..1000002059237.77 rows=445 width=44)
        ->  XN Sort  (cost=1000002059236.65..1000002059237.77 rows=445 width=44)
              ->  XN HashAggregate  (cost=2059217.08..2059217.08 rows=445 width=44)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on accountbillingflat  (cost=0.00..2045174.64 rows=1404244 width=44)
```

The actual execution is

[image]

And looking into the details of sequential scan we see

[image]

which is strange as both linkedaccountid and billingmonth are sort keys.

Comment: Can you clarify what is strange? Sort keys triggers range-restricted scan (check), group by causes local hash aggregation because linkedaccountid is the dist key (check), order by causes global merge sort because sort keys are across slices (check). Looks sensible.

Comment: Right, our understanding was that if column is specified as sort key then there will be no table scan, range restricted scan makes sense. Thanks